# mongodb group by first character

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a problem in mongodb.

I want to create aggregation witch result will be like this:

```
A 10
B 2
C 4
D 9
E 3
...
```

I have a column `words` in my table and I want to group my records according to first character of column `words`.

I find resolve for `sql` but not for mongo.

I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Please add more details explaining what you want to do, and consider using markup to make things clearer. For example, "I have a column `words` in my table" is easier to understand than "I have a column words in my table". (If that's what you mean to say.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't show what the docs in your collection look like, but you can use the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) collection method to do this:

```javascript
// Group by the first letter of the 'words' field of each doc in the 'test'
// collection while generating a count of the docs in each group.
db.test.aggregate({$group: {_id: {$substr: ['$words', 0, 1]}, count: {$sum: 1}}})
```